# Principal Component Analysis - linear or nonlinear relationships between variables?

Tags: statistics

I'm not a statistician but I realize that the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) goal is to detect the correlation between variables. It is not like linear regression because rather than attempting to predict the values, PCA is attempting to learn about the relationship between variables. What kind of relationships could be detected by PCA, linear or nonlinear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA is inherently linear being based on linear algebra. Of course the principles behind it may be extended to algorithms for nonlinear data, but they differ markedly from what we're used to with PCA.

PCA is used for dimensionality reduction. This could be in the concrete sense of finding 2D planes in 3D data or the more abstract of given a problem over 20 parameters, try to trim it down to say 2 or 3 combinations thereof in order to be managable computationally.

E.g. given a D dimensional problem space, can we apply an orthogonal transformation so that the solution only depends on d